# Can't find elements on web page using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to find text element on the web page (address is below)

[image]

I am interested in reddit post title. (it is pointed out on the screen)

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and inspected element and get:

```
<h2 class="s1ua9il2-0 hsWiTe" data-redditstyle="true">The problems of a dutchman in China.</h2>
```

There is no id and name. Only tag ('h2') and class ("s1ua9il2-0 hsWiTe"), right?

My code below doesn't work:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\vishniakov\Desktop\python bj\driver\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/9kxrv6/the_problems_of_a_dutchman_in_china/")
print(driver.title)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("s1ua9il2-0 hsWiTe")
#driver.quit()
```

ERROR:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

Also, finding by css_selector doesn't work too, when I use copy click:

[image]

Comment: https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html ?

Comment: You may want to use xpath instead of just get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

then,

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
```

Comment: I am very sorry, but this method doesn't work at next case: driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1l_l_dP99Y")
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="owner-name"]/a')
# element is name of the channel "MrVinylObsessive"                                              There is working video

Comment: You have to use elem.getText(). If you did not miss that, what error you are getting?

Comment: I miss that. Where should I use elem.getText().?

Comment: This way to get xpath helped me so much. just want to say that some websites change id of tags dinamicaly

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by xpath
f12 - click on element and copy xpath
for example:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/button')
```